# Form submission does not work when Yup validation is imported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, formik, yup

The validation I imported from the external file is running. However, the form submission function does not work.

I set the verification as follows and exported.

```
import * as Yup from 'yup';      
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
      mail: Yup.string()
        .email('Lütfen geçerli bir e-posta adresi giriniz!')
        .required('Boş bırakılamaz.'),
      password: Yup.string()
        .min(8, 'Şifreniz en az 8 karakter olmalıdır.')
        .required('Boş bırakılamaz.'),
    });
export default ValidationSchema;
```

I import it this way and use it with Formik.

```
 import validationSchema from './ValidationSchema';

  <Formik
            initialValues={{ mail: '', password: '' }}
            validationSchema={validationSchema}
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          >
            {({ errors, touched }) => (
```

This is how validation works. However, when the form is submitted, the handleSubmit function does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your validation is breaking. Please check your mail and password fields are meeting the validation criteria.

Comment: There is no problem with my verification. I get the warning message when it is not correct. However, when verification is provided, the form is not submitted.

Comment: Can you please share the full code of Formik and input tags you are using.

Comment: I use Field as an input tag. This is all the formik code.

Answer (score 0):

if the form is not submitted then, you are not calling the handleSubmit correctly
you can call it with this syntax when a button is clicked
`onPress={() => handleSubmit()}`

Comment: Isn't it done twice in this way to submit the form?